# Finding the running majority/ratio

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I have a table `players_in_teams`, that contains events of when a player either joins or leaves a team.

If >=60% of the players have the same first name, the team is be named after these players.  If <60%, then it does’t get a name. A player can only leave when they are in the team, and can only join if they are not in the team.

```sql
team_id date     player_name event_type   team_size  player_name_occurance  player_portion team_name  majority_team_portion
1       05-11-12  Joe        player_added    1       1                       1              team_joe   1
1       06-11-12  Tina       player_added    2       1                       0.5            NULL       NULL
1       07-11-12  Joe        player_added    3       2                       0.66           team_joe   0.66
1       07-11-12  Joe        player_added    4       3                       0.75           team_joe   0.75
1       08-11-12  Mark       player_added    5       1                       0.2            team_joe   0.6 
1       09-11-12  Jane       player_added    6       1                       0.16           NULL       NULL
1       10-11-12  Joe        player_deleted  5       2                       0.4            NULL       NULL 
1       11-11-12  Jane       player_deleted  4       0                       0              NULL       NULL
1       12-11-12  Tina       player_deleted  3       0                       0              team_joe   0.66 
1       13-11-12  Mark       player_deleted  2       0                       0              team_joe   1
```

I can see 4 scenarios:

1. Player joins and brings its own % up, above 60%.
2. Player leaves and brings down its own %, but its still above 60%
3. Player joins and bring another name below 60%
4. Player leaves and brings down its own %, causing another name to cross 60%

Scenarios 1 and 2 are fine but I'm struggling with 3 and 4, when the ratio indirectly changes.

I've tried using `LAG` to get the previous row, but the previous row may not always contain the majority.
I've tried other window functions like `mode` and `count(distinct)` but they have limitations with window frames.

What I think I need is the

- latest maximum `player_name_occurance`. If this/team_size is >=0.6 then get the player_name of that maximum.

There are millions of these events so I’d like to avoid any self joining if possible. Thanks in advance for any help/pointers

Comment: I doubt it is doable only with window functions. I did it using self join in Oracle [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/am_4q5yc), maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement a running algorithm like this is a UDFT in your favorite language (JS/Java/Python) that can go row by row, remember the count of each name, and then output for that row whatever name has more than 60%.

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-tabular-functions
- https://towardsdatascience.com/sql-puzzle-optimization-the-udtf-approach-for-a-decay-function-4b4b3cdc8596

It would be something like this:

```js
create or replace function more_than_60_udtf(name string)
returns table (team_name string)
language javascript
as $$
{
    processRow: function f(row, rowWriter, context){
        // add or remove the row.PLAYER_NAME from an internal counting structure
        rowWriter.writeRow({OUTPUT_COL: 
          // logic to output the name if >0.6
        });
    }        
    , initialize: function(argumentInfo, context) {
         this.your_internal_structure_that_keeps_running_count
    }
}
$$;
```

Then you would call it with something like:

```sql
select output_col, a.*
from my_table a
    , table(more_than_60_udtf(player_first_name) over(partition by team_id order by date));
```